# Getting Eclipse to read includes from makefile

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile

I have a makefile which compiles my code just fine when running make.
If a create a makefile project in eclipse and import my already existing makefile it is possible to build the project.
But Eclipse does not resolve names, as it cannot find my include files. Is there a way where Eclipse automatically can read include paths from the makefile?

My makefile looks like this

```
# Put your stlink folder here so make burn will work.
STLINK=~/Programs/stlink

# Put your source files here (or *.c, etc)
SRCS=main.c system_stm32f4xx.c ../src/*.c

# Binaries will be generated with this name (.elf, .bin, .hex, etc)
PROJ_NAME=blinky

# Put your STM32F4 library code directory here
STM_COMMON=../STM32F4-Discovery_FW_V1.1.0

# Normally you shouldn't need to change anything below this line!
#######################################################################################

CC=arm-none-eabi-gcc
OBJCOPY=arm-none-eabi-objcopy

CFLAGS  = -g -O2 -Wall -Tstm32_flash.ld
CFLAGS += -mlittle-endian -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb-interwork
CFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
CFLAGS += -I.

# Include files from STM libraries
CFLAGS += -I$(STM_COMMON)/Utilities/STM32F4-Discovery
CFLAGS += -I$(STM_COMMON)/Libraries/CMSIS/Include -I$(STM_COMMON)/Libraries/CMSIS/ST/STM32F4xx/Include
CFLAGS += -I$(STM_COMMON)/Libraries/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/inc
CFLAGS += -I ../include/

# add startup file to build
SRCS += $(STM_COMMON)/Libraries/CMSIS/ST/STM32F4xx/Source/Templates/TrueSTUDIO/startup_stm32f4xx.s
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)


.PHONY: proj

all: proj

proj: $(PROJ_NAME).elf

$(PROJ_NAME).elf: $(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
    $(OBJCOPY) -O ihex $(PROJ_NAME).elf $(PROJ_NAME).hex
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $(PROJ_NAME).elf $(PROJ_NAME).bin

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(PROJ_NAME).elf $(PROJ_NAME).hex $(PROJ_NAME).bin

# Flash the STM32F4
burn: proj
    $(STLINK)/st-flash write $(PROJ_NAME).bin 0x8000000
```

Comment: I don't think Eclipse will try to read your Makefile. However, if you use gcc or a compiler based on gcc, Eclipse can parse the calls to gcc as well as gcc's output to update it's set of includes folders, symbols, etc. It's a big part of Eclipse CDT actually.

Comment: @Tim but how do you make eclipse do that?

Comment: @Szundi it's called the indexer, you can look it up online. But basically it should work out of the box as long as the compiler calls are shown in the console.

Comment: @Tim, thanks. So basically it works out of the box, or at least it should. In my case with the latest 2018.09, it does not find out where the header files are, and it is my previous experience too. It is daunting to set up header file include locations in eclipse, it is like 10 pages in the makefile...

Comment: @Szundi All I can say is that it parses the `-Ipath/to/includes` in the console. Then I can see all the resolved paths in the `project properties->C/C++ General->Preprocessor Include Paths->GNU C->CDT GCC Build Output Parser`. Also I have relative paths and the sources are located in the project, i.e. I can reach them from the project explorer (but those are  linked folders). You can perhaps try to play with the `right-click->Index...` menu, e.g., Rebuild index.